# MIU Pagination - Set number of rows per page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I change the default rows per page (5) using the standard MIU Pagination from `import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';`? I want to show 10 rows per page but looking through the documentation I couldn't find a prop to handle this.

```
      <Pagination
        count={props.totalPages}
        page={props.pageNo}
        onChange={props.handleClick}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the docs, if you need further help, please don't hesitate to ask

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#table-pagination

Comment: This is for TablePagination but we are using Pagination

Comment: then you have to handle it by your own

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`siblingCount`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination/#props):

```js
const {
  Container,
  Pagination,
} = MaterialUI;

function App() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <Pagination count={11} defaultPage={6} siblingCount={5} />
    </Container>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

<div id="app"></div>
```

Make sure you use a number that is about half of what you want. For instance, if you want 10 bullets, `siblingCount={5}` will display at most 11 bullets (5 siblings before, 1 for the current page, 5 siblings after).

Comment: Looking to set the number of rows of content shown per page (using ul / li), not the pagination numbers. <Pagination> paginates after 5 li by default